# How to use not equal operator in java database query?

Tags: java, database, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am making a query in my managed bean. here is the code:

```
 try {
        PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM boats where age= ? and color <> ?");
        checkDB.setString(1, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("age"));
        checkDB.setString(1, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("color"));
        ResultSet res=(ResultSet) checkDB.executeQuery();
        return res;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

I am sure that this query works without the condition "color <> ?". But when i add this does not work. I think there is a problem about my not equal operator. I searched how it is used and saw the same usage as i did. I also tried "!=" but did not work either. I am using MySQL database. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the query directly on the DB?

Comment: As such things depend on the database you use, it would be very helpful, if you could tell us, which one you are using and maybe also the version of it.

Comment: @Korashen i am using MySQL, edited the question

Comment: Ok, MySQL supports both operators. But I think it was about the parameter index anyway.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, then what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you are using a wrong parameter index.
It should be:

```
    checkDB.setString(1, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("age"));
    checkDB.setString(2, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("color"));
```

Comment: ah you are right while copy pasting i forgot it. Sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 1):

```
    checkDB.setString(1, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("color"));
```

should be:

```
    checkDB.setString(2, (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("color"));
```